# Wifi for Ubuntu 12.04.1 on Beaglebone

Tags: wireless, realtek

I have a Beaglebone running Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS with a Realtek Wifi USB dongle:

```
ubuntu@arm:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I am able to connect just fine to my Netgear R6300 with the following /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# WiFi Example
auto wlan1
iface wlan1 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid "FalkorSystems"
    wpa-psk  "<omitted>"
```

However I am trying to connect to my Verizon MiFi device "Jetpack 4260L", and I'm not having any luck. I'm able to connect fine to the MiFi from my Mac. The MiFi is setup with WPA2, just like the Netgear R6300

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# WiFi Example
auto wlan1
iface wlan1 inet dhcp
       wpa-ssid "FalkorMifi"
       wpa-psk  "<omitted>"
```

I've also tried configuring the MiFi with an open network and I used:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# WiFi Example
auto wlan1
iface wlan1 inet dhcp
       wireless-ssid "FalkorMifi"
```

I've also created an access point on my Mac using the instructions here:

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-make-your-mac-a-wifi-access-point.html

and I created it without any encryption, and I wasn't able to connect.

I would do:

```
> ifdown wlan1
> ifup wlan1
```

and the ifup command would hang.

I also tried rebooting rather than doing ifdown/ifup.

dmesg would tell me, when it connects successfully to my Netgear:

```
[   22.805207] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[   25.983702] rtl8192cu: MAC address: 00:e0:4c:09:25:15
[   25.983752] rtl8192cu: Board Type 0
[   26.241514] rtlwifi: rx_max_size 15360, rx_urb_num 8, in_ep 1
[   26.241561] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2412 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[   26.241589] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   26.241608] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2417 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[   26.241630] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   26.241647] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2422 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[   26.241669] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   26.241686] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2427 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[   26.241707] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   26.241725] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2432 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[   26.241746] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   26.241764] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2437 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[   26.241785] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   26.241802] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2442 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[   26.241824] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   26.241841] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2447 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[   26.241863] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   26.241880] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2452 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[   26.241901] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   26.241919] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2457 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[   26.241940] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   26.241957] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2462 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[   26.241979] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   26.241996] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2467 MHz as custom regd has no rule that fits a 20 MHz wide channel
[   26.242015] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2472 MHz as custom regd has no rule that fits a 20 MHz wide channel
[   26.242034] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2484 MHz as custom regd has no rule that fits a 20 MHz wide channel
[   26.242365] cfg80211: Ignoring regulatory request Set by core since the driver uses its own custom regulatory domain
[   26.242916] cfg80211: Pending regulatory request, waiting for it to be processed...
[   26.351209] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   26.354357] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192cu
[   26.890970] udevd[271]: renamed network interface wlan0 to wlan1
[   27.428810] init: udev-fallback-graphics main process (499) terminated with status 1
[   27.502462] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[   27.557706] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[   27.560618] rtl8192c_common: Loading firmware file rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw.bin
[   28.301232] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan1: link is not ready
[   28.739235] init: isc-dhcp-server pre-start process (536) terminated with status 127
[   43.829532] wlan1: authenticate with 84:1b:5e:ee:cd:8c (try 1)
[   43.832231] wlan1: authenticated
[   43.834082] wlan1: associate with 84:1b:5e:ee:cd:8c (try 1)
[   43.839932] wlan1: RX AssocResp from 84:1b:5e:ee:cd:8c (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
[   43.839980] wlan1: associated
[   43.858354] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan1: link becomes ready
[   54.338125] wlan1: no IPv6 routers present
```

When it fails to connect to my MiFi (configured as an open network):

```
[   20.060175] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[   20.905690] rtl8192cu: MAC address: 00:e0:4c:09:25:15
[   20.905740] rtl8192cu: Board Type 0
[   21.561046] rtlwifi: rx_max_size 15360, rx_urb_num 8, in_ep 1
[   21.561093] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2412 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[   21.561119] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   21.561137] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2417 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[   21.561159] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   21.561176] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2422 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[   21.561198] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   21.561215] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2427 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[   21.561237] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   21.561254] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2432 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[   21.561276] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   21.561293] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2437 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[   21.561314] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   21.561331] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2442 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[   21.561352] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   21.561370] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2447 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[   21.561391] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   21.561408] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2452 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[   21.561430] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   21.561447] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2457 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[   21.561469] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   21.561485] cfg80211: Updating information on frequency 2462 MHz for a 20 MHz width channel with regulatory rule:
[   21.561507] cfg80211: 2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   21.561525] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2467 MHz as custom regd has no rule that fits a 20 MHz wide channel
[   21.561544] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2472 MHz as custom regd has no rule that fits a 20 MHz wide channel
[   21.561563] cfg80211: Disabling freq 2484 MHz as custom regd has no rule that fits a 20 MHz wide channel
[   21.561894] cfg80211: Ignoring regulatory request Set by core since the driver uses its own custom regulatory domain
[   21.562460] cfg80211: Pending regulatory request, waiting for it to be processed...
[   22.324375] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   22.327427] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192cu
[   22.782272] udevd[264]: renamed network interface wlan0 to wlan1
[   23.326273] init: udev-fallback-graphics main process (497) terminated with status 1
[   34.190986] rtl8192cu: MAC auto ON okay!
[   34.224398] rtl8192cu: Tx queue select: 0x05
[   34.225925] rtl8192c_common: Loading firmware file rtlwifi/rtl8192cufw.bin
[   34.741921] ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan1: link is not ready
```

Does anyone have any ideas here?

Thanks!